# Passing Enum flag from WCF to json client

Tags: json, wcf

I have an Enum defined in a C# dll with the `[Flags]` attribute:

```
    [Flags]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "MyApp")]
    public enum MobileNotifications
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        None,

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        Msg1,

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        Msg2,

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        Msg3,

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [EnumMember]
        Msg4
    }
```

When I call a method "GetFlags", it returns the value as a single `Int` value.

```
MobileNotifications GetNotifications()
{
   return Msg1 | Msg4;
}
```

The method above returns `5` as a value.  Is there a way for WCF to pass an enum flag that can be parsed for json?

This is a .NET 4.0 WCF service.

Comment: Well, `5` can be parsed as JSON (it's a JSON number). What exactly do you want the method to return?

Comment: Yes, but 5 is not an Enum or flag value.  Its just the values of Msg1 and Msg4 being combined.  Would I not get the same value if I returned Msg2|Msg3?

Comment: If you have a `[Flags]` enumeration, you should define the values of the members as powers of 2. This way there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define explicit enumeration constants in powers of two to avoid any overlapping of differnt value combinations (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/system.flagsattribute.aspx). In order to return that to a Json client in a meaningful way, I'd suggest to `ToString()` it which actually creates a comma-separated list of the actual member names (which you can then parse on the client side). Example:

```
[Flags]
public enum MobileNotifications
{
    None = 0,
    Msg1 = 1,
    Msg2 = 2,
    Msg3 = 4
}

var value = MobileNotifications.Msg1 | MobileNotifications.Msg3;
var asString = string.Format("{0}", value);  // will create: "Msg1, Msg3"
```

Comment: I had read the docs, but was hoping for a better solution than parsing the int in to its separate values.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would have another look at this design. What does 5 mean? It can be made up a couple of different combinations can't it - Msg 1 | Msg4, Msg 2| Msg 3 etc.. The same goes for the rest. Can the consumer differentiate between the combinations? If not I would suggest making this more explicit or actually changing the enum values so that the combinations are unique such as

None =0,
Msg1 = 1,
Msg2 = 2,
Msg3 = 4,
Msg4 = 8